# Install default gcc version

Tags: gcc

I've installed gcc on my ubuntu 18.4.
The default for this ubuntu version is 7.4.0, but a 7.5.0 version was installed on my computer. 
How do I downgrade the version to the default?

Edit: I'll be more specific, when trying to install Nvidia display driver, I get an error:

`The kernel was built with gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu~18.04.1), But the current compiler version is cc (ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu~18.04) 7.5.0`

Comment: How have you installed newer version? Could you explain?

Comment: With command: `sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc g++ make binutils linux-headers-uname -r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sudo apt install gcc
```

It installs 7.5.0 version which is default now. So no need to downgrade to default version. 7.5.0 is default for 18.04.04 LTS.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

user@pc:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
```

GCC 7.4.0 is default for Ubuntu disco 19.04 which is EOL now and is not supported on this resource.

And it is also available for 19.10 in ports section for some specific platforms:
*7.4.0-14ubuntu2 [ports]: arm64 armhf ppc64el s390x*

[Reference](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc-7)

Comment: By your refrence, it seems like you're right. But anyway, when I try to install Nvidia driver, I get an error - "The kernel was built with gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu~18.04.1), But the current compiler version is cc (ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu~18.04) 7.5.0"